# One of the variables modified by an inplace operation

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I am relatively new to Pytorch. Here I want to use this model to generate some images, however as this was written before Pytorch 1.5, since the gradient calculation has been fixed then, this is the error message.

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been 
modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [1, 512, 4, 4]] 
is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. 
Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that 
failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

I have looked at past examples and am not sure what is the problem here, I believe it is happening within this region but I don’t know where! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def process(self, images, edges, masks):
self.iteration += 1

    # zero optimizers
    self.gen_optimizer.zero_grad()
    self.dis_optimizer.zero_grad()


    # process outputs
    outputs = self(images, edges, masks)
    gen_loss = 0
    dis_loss = 0


    # discriminator loss
    dis_input_real = torch.cat((images, edges), dim=1)
    dis_input_fake = torch.cat((images, outputs.detach()), dim=1)
    dis_real, dis_real_feat = self.discriminator(dis_input_real)        # in: (grayscale(1) + edge(1))
    dis_fake, dis_fake_feat = self.discriminator(dis_input_fake)        # in: (grayscale(1) + edge(1))
    dis_real_loss = self.adversarial_loss(dis_real, True, True)
    dis_fake_loss = self.adversarial_loss(dis_fake, False, True)
    dis_loss += (dis_real_loss + dis_fake_loss) / 2


    # generator adversarial loss
    gen_input_fake = torch.cat((images, outputs), dim=1)
    gen_fake, gen_fake_feat = self.discriminator(gen_input_fake)        # in: (grayscale(1) + edge(1))
    gen_gan_loss = self.adversarial_loss(gen_fake, True, False)
    gen_loss += gen_gan_loss


    # generator feature matching loss
    gen_fm_loss = 0
    for i in range(len(dis_real_feat)):
        gen_fm_loss += self.l1_loss(gen_fake_feat[i], dis_real_feat[i].detach())
    gen_fm_loss = gen_fm_loss * self.config.FM_LOSS_WEIGHT
    gen_loss += gen_fm_loss


    # create logs
    logs = [
        ("l_d1", dis_loss.item()),
        ("l_g1", gen_gan_loss.item()),
        ("l_fm", gen_fm_loss.item()),
    ]

    return outputs, gen_loss, dis_loss, logs

def forward(self, images, edges, masks):
    edges_masked = (edges * (1 - masks))
    images_masked = (images * (1 - masks)) + masks
    inputs = torch.cat((images_masked, edges_masked, masks), dim=1)
    outputs = self.generator(inputs)                                    # in: [grayscale(1) + edge(1) + mask(1)]
    return outputs

def backward(self, gen_loss=None, dis_loss=None):
    if dis_loss is not None:
        dis_loss.backward()
    self.dis_optimizer.step()

    if gen_loss is not None:
        gen_loss.backward()
    self.gen_optimizer.step()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compute the loss for the discriminator and for the generator in one go and have the both back-propagations back-to-back like this:

```
if dis_loss is not None:
    dis_loss.backward()
self.dis_optimizer.step()

if gen_loss is not None:
    gen_loss.backward()
self.gen_optimizer.step()
```

Here's the reason why: when you call `self.dis_optimizer.step()`, you effectively in-place modify the parameters of the discriminator, the very same that were used to compute `gen_loss` which you are trying to backpropagate on. This is not possible.

You have to compute `dis_loss` backpropagate, update the weights of the discriminator, and clear the gradients. Only then can you compute `gen_loss` with the newly updated discriminator weights. Finally, backpropagate on the generator.

This [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) is a good walkthrough over a typical GAN training.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer exactly to your question but I got this when trying to use a "custom" distributed optimizer e.g. I was using Cherry's optimizer and accidentially moving the model to a DDP model at the same time. Once I only moved the model to device according to how cherry worked I stopped getting this issue.

context: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/263

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. For more details, please see [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-pytorch1-5-runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/90256/4?u=peter_pack).

```py
def backward(self, gen_loss=None, dis_loss=None):
    if dis_loss is not None:
        dis_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)  # modified here
    self.dis_optimizer.step()

    if gen_loss is not None:
        gen_loss.backward()
    self.gen_optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be late a bit, but here is what worked for me:

```
def backward(self, gen_loss=None, dis_loss=None):
    if dis_loss is not None:
       dis_loss.backward()

    if gen_loss is not None:
       gen_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    self.dis_optimizer.step()
    self.gen_optimizer.step()
```